# mongodb adding values to array field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, body-parser

Hey guys not giving an example since the question is pretty straightforward.

I have a mongodb schema in which I have a field called Teamnames which is an array so
Teamnames: [String]

I am using body parser middleware to accept data from a form on my client side. There are about 10 different text boxes each having name as teamname1, teamname2, etc etc .

Whats the right syntax to update the mongodb field? I am doing findOneAndUpdate to retrieve the record from my collection after submitting the update and I wanted to update the Teamname array with the values. But I am kind of confused with the syntax and whats the right way to approach this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Even though you said it's straight forward, I still think you need to give some sample input and output that you expect to avoid misinterpretation. It's still not clear to me how the input from the checkboxes look like and how you want the final array to be when receiving certain checkbox values.

Comment: Ok, I have misread the question, apology. So you should have an object with the keys `"teamname1", "teamname2", ...`, right? Any reason why you don't use `"teamname[]"` as the input name to send the fields as an array? The question title says you want to *add* the values, are you actually trying to *replace* the values?

Comment: sorry bud, maybe my question was silly. I am trying to understand the syntax more than anything else. I can create an array from all the textboxes no proble. But whats the syntax to use while doing collection.FindOneAnd Update. Should I use $push or $set or simply { <FieldName> : obj[] }

Comment: `$push` with `$each` is for appending the current array with the new array elements. you can use `$set` to replace all the current array with the new array. Which one are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const value = await YourModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
          $set: { teamnames: yourFormData }
         },
         {
          new: true,
          upsert: true,
        });
```

Comment: @SandeepNair no worries!